# Ruby ffi library error when running on Apple ARM chip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arm, ffi, apple-m1

Ruby 2.6.6

I am receiving the following error I believe when any gem is dependent on the `ffi` gem (in this example, taxjar).

```
rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                
TypeError: unable to resolve type 'size_t'                                                                                                                   
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/ffi-1.9.25/lib/ffi/types.rb:69:in `find_type'               
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/ffi-1.9.25/lib/ffi/library.rb:585:in `find_type'      
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/ffi-1.9.25/lib/ffi/library.rb:392:in `block in callback'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/ffi-1.9.25/lib/ffi/library.rb:392:in `map'                                      
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/ffi-1.9.25/lib/ffi/library.rb:392:in `callback'                                
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/http-parser-1.2.3/lib/http-parser/types.rb:311:in `<module:HttpParser>'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/http-parser-1.2.3/lib/http-parser/types.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/http-parser-1.2.3/lib/http-parser.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/http-4.4.1/lib/http/response/parser.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/http-4.4.1/lib/http/connection.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/http-4.4.1/lib/http/client.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'                             
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/http-4.4.1/lib/http.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'                                  
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bundler/gems/taxjar-ruby-56a947d6cde5/lib/taxjar/api/request.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bundler/gems/taxjar-ruby-56a947d6cde5/lib/taxjar/api/utils.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bundler/gems/taxjar-ruby-56a947d6cde5/lib/taxjar/api/api.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bundler/gems/taxjar-ruby-56a947d6cde5/lib/taxjar/client.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/skylight-5.0.1/lib/skylight/probes.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bundler/gems/taxjar-ruby-56a947d6cde5/lib/taxjar.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am guessing this could be resolved on a more recent release of the `ffi` gem (currently on 1.9.25), but it's a dependency of a few gems and was curious if anyone has run into this and if it could be solved in another way?

```
> gem dependency ffi --reverse-dependencies
Gem ffi-1.9.25
  rake (~> 10.1, development)
  rake-compiler (~> 1.0, development)
  rake-compiler-dock (~> 0.6.2, development)
  rspec (~> 2.14.1, development)
  rubygems-tasks (~> 0.2.4, development)
  Used by
    ethon-0.12.0 (ffi (>= 1.3.0))
    ffi-compiler-1.0.1 (ffi (>= 1.0.0))
    rb-inotify-0.9.10 (ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2))
```

Comment: Whenever dealing with M1 issues, always check with Ruby 2.7 latest and 3.0 latest. 2.6 is the last to get patched. If this is a bug, it's worth raising an issue on the gem's project if applicable.

Comment: @Tony did you figure this out? How did you workaround this?

Comment: @Pandaiolo I didn't, i am typing to you on an Intel Mac XD XD

Answer (score 0):

You should simply recompile:

`gem pristine ffi sassc`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).